# How to change the value of a certain core data across VCs/ How to know the index of a created CoreData?

Tags: core-data, segue, viewcontroller

I start from a TableView to create and store user information. This is how I create a core data entity called "`Trials`" in `CreateTrialViewController`. And I can successfully fetch it in the `tableViewController` after I come back to it.

```
       let trial : Trials = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Trials", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as? Trials
        {  
            trial.project = theProject.text
            trial.record = theRecord.text
            trial.notes = theNotes.text
            trial.percentile = ""         
            managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
        }        
'
```

But after I create the Trial, I will get some calculated results from the accelerometer in the next `measureViewController`, and I want to save the result into '`trial.percentile`'.

I have already converted the results into a string, so I can write it directly into the core data attribute. **But how can I know the index of this core data that I just created?** Should I try to use '`segue`' to transmit?

In the tableView it fetches in a ascending sequence of date, so the index is clear. But here in the following VC how to know the index? I still couldn't figure this out by myself... The sequence of my VCs is: TableViewController -> CreateTrialViewController -> MeasureViewController -> TableViewController (start again)

Comment: are you using a [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/) (as you should be)? It has a `indexPathForObject:` method that does what you want.

Comment: Yes, I use ´NSFetchedResultsController´  in the TableViewController, because in the tableView you click on certain row and it can fetch the details and present it. But do you mean I should use the ´NSFetchedResultsController´ also in the MeasureViewController? How can I know which indexPath is it, without clicking on certain row of the table? This is the problem I couldn't solve...

Comment: I guess you mean to use ´indexPathForObject´ to get the index?  But then should I transmit the ´object´ using ´segue´ ?  or How can I know which object I should fetch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table view controller can keep a reference to the newly created object. Insert the object (trial) in the original view controller and pass it on to the next controller in `prepareForSegue`. So the `CreateTrialViewController` starts out with a blank object to which the table view controller has a reference.

You configure the object, go to the measure controller, modify the object. When done, you pop these two controllers from the navigation stack and are back in your original table view controller.

Because your table view controller has the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` enabled, it will update itself to reflect the data of your new object. Remember, you still have a reference to this object, so you can just use `indexPathForObject` to retrieve its index path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am a little confused, how can I "configure the object" and modify it in the `measureViewController`? Now I actually insert/create the object in `CreateTrialViewController`, so when back to `tableViewController`, there is no problem of fetching it. The difficulty I have is how to modify it in the `measureViewController`...

Comment: The same way. Pass it on in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: I tried to use Segue, but I failed several times. I guess it is because I used `segue.identifier == "createTrial"` to create the object, and I couldn't pass the object which I just created to the next VC in the same segue?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved it by creating the object in `tableViewController`, and use `Segue` twice. Thanks for your help!